# CORS requests with node.js/express and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I would like to implement a very simple CORS scenario. Here's my server written in node.js/express:

```
var express        = require('express');
var morgan         = require('morgan');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var app            = express();
var router         = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Test-Header');
    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request arrived');
    res.json({data: 'hello'});
    next();
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride());  
app.use('/', router);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express is up on ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

To complement this I have a very simple AngularJS file as well:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var config = {
            headers:  {
                'X-Test-Header': 'Test Header Data'
            }
        };

        $scope.test = 'Hello World';
        $scope.getData = function () {
            console.log('clicked');
            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/', config).
            success(function (data, status) {
                console.log('Status: ', status);
                console.log('Data: ', data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status) {
                console.log('Status: ', status);
                console.log('Data: ', data || 'Request failed');
            });
        }
    });
```

The output in my console for the node/express app is simply:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
OPTIONS / 200 4.767 ms - 3
Request arrived
GET / 200 2.572 ms - 16
```

And in the browser's console I see: 'clicked'.

On the network tab I see that there were two request made once I have clicked the button - one OPTIONS that returned a 200 OK, and a GET method which is pending forever.

[image: network tab]

So my question is of course, why am I experiencing this behaviour? I tried digging and read quite a few articles and tried their suggestions but none of them worked.

Comment: I'm really not sure, but I'd guess you possibly have some kind of infinite loop in your Express middleware. I don't see any obvious problems with your CORS setup (and even if there were a problem, I don't see that causing a never-ending "pending" state on the GET).

Comment: `$http.get` should return a `$q` object, which you can use `.then` on to set up a `notifyCallback` (third argument to `.then`), which I believe should fire to report XHR `progress` events, but I'm not 100% sure. Try adding something like `$http.get(..).then(undefined, undefined, function(result) { console.log("progress"); })`. If that works, it would confirm that the hangup is happening after your JSON is sent.

Comment: hi @apsillers - $http.get('<url>', config).
                then(undefined, undefined, function (result) {
                    console.log('progress');
                }); -- does not return the message 'progress' to the console

Comment: Well, that doesn't prove anything conclusively -- I'm not actually 100% sure Angular's `$http` promise uses notify callbacks. Anyway, judging from the fact that you see `Request arrived` in the console, it looks like the `get` callback is running, and therefore the hangup must be sometime after that. Try removing the `app.use` calls after `app.get` one by one and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: naw - nothing has changed unfortunately

Comment: I just checked your code and it is working just fine. Are you sending any header in request that is not in your allowed headers list? Do you get any error message in console?

Comment: Did you try it with Express4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough the following has fixed the issue:

```
router.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request arrived');
    res.type('application/json');
    res.json({datax: 'hello'});
    next();
});
```

notice the diff --> `router.get('/')`  vs `router.all('/')`. I'm a bit baffled why this is happening though.

**UPDATE**
Here's a much better code that I put together, now that I understand this a bit more ...

```
app.route('/')
    .options(function (req, res, next) {
        res.status(200).end();
        next();
    })
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.json({data: 'hello'});
    });
```

And here's a quick writeup about my findings: http://tamas.io/node-jsexpress-cors-implementation/